# Write multiple rasters in R

Tags: raster, r

I am trying to write a series of raster files into a new folder (after doing some image processing). However, when using my code, the files are but are not in the folder that I have created for that purpose.

I say they are but they are not because when I run my code and take a look inside the folder that I have created, a file pops-up, disappears, pops-up, disappears and this goes until I hit stop the R console.

Here is my code

```
Img.Raster <- list()
for (k in 1:length(list.pics)){
  Img.Raster[[k]] <- raster(list.pics[k])
  extent(Img.Raster[[k]])=c(coordinate.one.Image$CenterLeftx[[k]], coordinate.one.Image$CenterRightx[[k]],
                            coordinate.one.Image$CenterBottomy[[k]], coordinate.one.Image$CenterTopy[[k]])
  proj4string(Img.Raster[[k]]) <- "+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  writeRaster(Img.Raster[[k]],filename =paste0("/Users/Juan/Desktop/Images_Folder/"
                                                , "Img_",names(list.pics[[k]])), format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

`list.Image` is a variable that contains 1745 images

Those anyone know what could be wrong?

Suggestion by @Jul

```
for (k in 1:length(list.pics)){
  Img.Raster[[k]] <- raster(list.pics[k])
  extent(Img.Raster[[k]])=c(coordinate.one.Image$CenterLeftx[[k]], coordinate.one.Image$CenterRightx[[k]],
                            coordinate.one.Image$CenterBottomy[[k]], coordinate.one.Image$CenterTopy[[k]])
  proj4string(Img.Raster[[k]]) <- "+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  writeRaster(Img.Raster[[k]],filename =paste0("/Users/Juan/Desktop/Images_Folder/"
                                                , "Img_",stringr::str_pad(string = k,width = 4,side = "left",pad=0),
                                               format="GTiff",overwrite=T)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `names(list.pics[[k]])` to `names(list.pics[k])`.

I think you want the names of each element in the list (presumably 1745 unique names in total), not the names within each raster element, which I'd guess are the same for every element. The appearing/disappearing behaviour is probably because every file is being given the same filename and you've set `overwrite=TRUE`. It will probably throw a 'file already exists' error without the `overwrite` argument.

EDIT after comment thread:
Please ensure you are passing unique filenames to the `writeRaster` call. 
Swapping `names(list.pics[k])` for `stringr::str_pad(string = k,width = 4,side = "left",pad=0)` should work.

Suggestion

```
for (k in 1:length(list.pics)){
  Img.Raster[[k]] <- raster(list.pics[k])
  extent(Img.Raster[[k]])=c(coordinate.one.Image$CenterLeftx[[k]], coordinate.one.Image$CenterRightx[[k]],
                            coordinate.one.Image$CenterBottomy[[k]], coordinate.one.Image$CenterTopy[[k]])
  proj4string(Img.Raster[[k]]) <- "+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  writeRaster(Img.Raster[[k]],filename =paste0("/Users/Juan/Desktop/Images_Folder/", "Img_",stringr::str_pad(string = k,width = 4,side = "left",pad=0)),format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response; unfortunately, the appearing and disappearing behavior is still happening after making the changes that you suggested.

Comment: Are you sure you are piping in unique names? What happens if you set `overwrite=F`?

Comment: By changing `overwrite= F` I get the following error `Error in .getGDALtransient(x, filename = filename, options = options,  : 
  filename exists; use overwrite=TRUE`

Comment: Then the filename you are creating each time is the same, meaning all of the elements in list.pics have the exact same name. If you use `stringr::str_pad(string = k,width = 4,side = "left",pad=0)` in place of `names(list.pics[k])`, then it should work.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are suggesting me; however, I have added to the original post, what I believe you are telling me to do. By running that I still don't get all my files in the folder, then again I am not sure if that is what you are suggesting me.

Comment: Please be clear on what happens when you run that code. Same behaviour as before? A new error message?

Comment: I get an unexpected closing bracket message `Error: unexpected '}' in:
"                                               format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
}"`

Comment: The `paste0` call should look like `paste0("/Users/Juan/Desktop/Images_Folder/", "Img_",stringr::str_pad(string = k,width = 4,side = "left",pad=0))`. You dropped one of the closing brackets.

Comment: I see what I was missing. By fixing that now it works, I am seeing files appearing in the folder. Thank you @Jul for your help!

Comment: would you mind explaining what you did? Thanks

Comment: Your previous code was piping in the exact same file name every time. That's why it kept appearing and disappearing, each loop was overwriting the previously exported raster. My code simply ensured each loop produced a different file name for the export.  You can add `print(names(list.pics[k]))` somewhere in your original loop code and add `print(stringr::str_pad(string = k,width = 4,side = "left",pad=0))` somewhere in the adjusted loop to see what I mean.